# StackOverflowError While in SBT's Compile

Tags: scala, build, sbt

While building (either with compile or test:compile), I get this error:

```
[info] [specializing CorrelationDal.scala]
[error] {file:/home/bamboo/.../}batch/compile:compile: java.lang.StackOverflowError
[error] Total time: 20 s, completed Feb 28, 2012 7:32:08 AM
```

As you can tell, I've set the '-verbose' option in the scalacOption key.

I decided to try and give the compilation process a larger stack size using:

```
(fork := true) ++ (javaOptions += "-Xss4G")
```

But that changed nothing.

I've tried to inspect the changes I made to CorrelationDal.scala and made some attempts at relaxing the amount of inference it needs to do (explicitly noting types, removing chained creation of iterables, etc.), but I can't really tell which were the culprits without internal understanding of the Scala compiler.

Does anyone have any clues as to how to get to the heart of the issue?

Comment: Did you try compiling manually? Can you isolate the part of the source code of the compilation unit that triggers the stack overflow?

Comment: I'm working on that. What's more incredible is that locally (on my MacOSX Lion machine) it works just fine, but on the Amazon Elastic instance it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is an issue with string concatenation. If you concatenate too many strings, like this:

```
"string" + "other string" + variable + "string" + ...
```

You'll get to this. I assume this is because of the type inferrence mechanism in the compiler that just tries too hard. Hope it will be fixed in a future version (I'm using 2.9.1...)

Comment: Does that sequence, by any chance, starts with a variable? That would make sense to me. At any rate, I assume you didn't call `.toString` on any of these variables, and they are not `String` themselves? I'd like to see an example of that -- it might be worth further investigation.

Comment: It does not start with a variable and putting `.toString` on all of the variables which are not strings to begin with doesn't make a difference.

Comment: In that case, I'd open a ticket with the smallest example you can come up with. It will probably be closed as won't fix, but it is useful to have these things documented and, besides, maybe it won't. Scala 2.10 is most likely to have string interpolation, which will make this moot.

Answer (score 6):

After I add -Xss2M in the sbt script file, it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

That parameter is meaningless -- you are not running, just compiling.

You have to change the stack size for SBT itself. Just edit the `sbt` script and change it.

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work either. But still - won't the compiler be forked and the javaOptions sent to it too?

Comment: @OmervanKloeten No forking takes place, and one can see by looking at the reverse dependencies showned by `inspect java-options` that it isn't used for anything but `runner`. Now, if even 4G are not enough, maybe you have created an infinite type inference loop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'll remove those lines. Still checking the source, but I can't find what's ailing the compiler just yet... Any suggestions?

Comment: @OmervanKloeten Remove source code until you find a smallist set of files that cause the problem. You can then try to declare types explicitly to find which inference is causing the problem (assuming that's really the problem). Also, try `last compile` after getting the error to retrieve the stack trace, which might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the `last compile` tip! I'll use it next time. However, you can see from my own answer to the question that I have already found the cause for this. Thanks for the help :)