# sbt compilation causes stackoverflow error

Tags: scala, sbt, stack-overflow

I have been facing this error for sometime now. Totally irritated because of this. Tried all the similar solutions seen in stackoverflow and other sites.

I have a 4 separate scala projects. Out of those, I am getting StackOverflow error on compilation of tow projects. These two projects are the biggest ones out of the 4 projects. 
I am getting this error when I try to build the project in Ubuntu Server machine. I tried increasing the Xmx options in sbt config file, but with no success.

Can anyone please help me to solve this, as I am going mad because of this. If I build the project 10 times, it will get succeeded in 1 or 2 attempts.

What I understood from the error log is that the issue comes with type checking. But, I have no idea where that occurs.

One of the failing projects have over 1000 classes/traits (without including case classes).

**Details**:

```
Ubuntu Server(14)
Sbt : 0.13.6 and 0.13.8 tried
Scala Version : 2.11.6
JDK: 1.8
```

A few lines of the error is pasted below:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:696)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$96.apply(Typers.scala:4523)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$96.apply(Typers.scala:4523)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4522)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4578)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:696)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5480)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adaptMember(Erasure.scala:642)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:696)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$96.apply(Typers.scala:4523)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$96.apply(Typers.scala:4523)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4522)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4578)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:696)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedArg(Typers.scala:3163)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$class.typedArgWithFormal$1(PatternTypers.scala:112)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$$anonfun$2.apply(PatternTypers.scala:115)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$$anonfun$2.apply(PatternTypers.scala:115)
    at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$map$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:46)
    at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$$anonfun$map$extension$1.apply(Tuple2Zipped.scala:44)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.runtime.Tuple2Zipped$.map$extension(Tuple2Zipped.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.PatternTypers$PatternTyper$class.typedArgsForFormals(PatternTypers.scala:115)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedArgsForFormals(Typers.scala:111)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$handleMonomorphicCall$1(Typers.scala:3469)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.doTypedApply(Typers.scala:3494)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4544)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4578)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(E
```

Comment: You need to change `-Xss`. Try `-Xss3m`

Comment: @jrudolph Where should I make that change? In sbtconfig.txt ? or somewhere else?

Comment: Te same way you changed `-Xmx`. Propably in your sbt launcher script.

Comment: @jrudolph : Thanks. I will add that and try if it works.

Comment: @jrudolph I added -Xss3m to sbtconfig.txt file. But same issue still present.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482243/stackoverflowerror-while-in-sbts-compile

Comment: Try running with `sbt -mem 2048`. If that works you can create an `.sbtopts` file in the project root and include that flag, i.e. a file that contains a line with `-mem 2048`.

Comment: Set your `SBT_OPTS` on the machine, this example has `-Xss2m` stack size, pretty common issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280839/how-to-set-heap-size-for-sbt/15281562#15281562

Answer (score 4):

This has been affecting Scala since 2.11.4 till 2.11.6 afaik. It doesn't appears as fixed on the latest release notes for 2.11.7.

Fortunately following the [track](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9355) on the issue tracker it's a duplicated [ticket](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9155) with an answer here on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510867/scala-2-11-5-compiler-crash-with-type-aliases-and-manifests)

Without the source code is harder to give more indications but that should definitely be a good pointer to find the issue and apply the proposed solution

Comment: I am using a lot of generics, but as mentioned in the ticket, we do not have manifest with Any. I tried all the memory related settings, but with no use.

Comment: You didn't mention that you haven't manifest. Anyway you can try a) searching for `Manifest` usage in the libraries you might be using, it's likely some of them are using it b) Upgrade your project to Scala 2.11.7 c) Report the bug to scala-lang.org

Comment: Just to be clear, I am using Manifest in some places for json deserialization. For eg: def extractEntity(json: String)(implicit m: Manifest[E]): E = parse(json).extract[E], where E is a trait called as BaseEntity with some common fields(id, isActive etc). Currently, I am using 2.11.6. I will try with 2.11.7 and check if the issue exist.

Comment: If the `Manifest` usage is within your code I suggest you to replace them with `TypeTags` and `ClassTags` [see this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html). As it's gonna be deprecated it's possible that the Scala guys won't fix the bug at all, as I said it doesn't appear on the recent 2.11.7 release notes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Json4s's extract method is expecting Manifest as an implicit parameter. I need to try how to get away without using that method in that case.

Comment: I tried removing all the implicit Manifest, but the issue remains same :(

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the configuration changes, but didn't work in the machine. So I had skipped this for almost a month. Recently, I tried building the project in `Jenkins` and was getting the same error. Then I upgraded sbt 0.13.8 and added the jvm flag `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx1024M -Xss16M` to the jenkins build flag. And so far, all the compilations have been successful. 
I remember adding the jvm flag to sbt config file, but was getting the same error. But now, it is working fine in jenkins after adding that flag.